# correct way to use decorators angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using an angular-bootstrap-calendar repository, documentation allows me to add my custom template, just adding

```
app.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('mwlCalendarDayDirective', function($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];
    delete directive.template; //the calendar uses template instead of template-url so you need to delete this
    directive.templateUrl = 'path/to/my/slide/box/template.html';
    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

this is me well, but my question is, to replace with another template, it retains the same controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly fine to decorate directives like that, they are just services with `Directive` suffix that contain arrays of [DDOs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api) (in the order of their registration). This approach modifies the specified properties while keeping the rest of DDO intact.

The process is straight-forward for other DDO properties except for `compile` / (post)`link` / `pre`(link), which are a bit tricky to patch.